# Alternative or similar tools for graylog2

Tags: syslog

I want to parse the syslogs and store in the mongodb. From web search i got graylog2. Is there any alternative for graylog2 ? suggest me similar tool ...

Thanks

Comment: what limitation are you hitting with splunk?

Comment: You are looking for a front-end too which provides search/charts or only a tool to parse the logs and then load into mongodb?

Answer (score 1):

did u try the splunk and logstash . These tools similar to graylog2.

Comment: thanks for the reply. i tried but these tools are not using the mongodb for storage. And splunk is limited.

Answer (score 1):

Logstash can be configured to index into mongodb and it is free just like graylogs.

You can find the documentation to use mongodb here:
http://logstash.net/docs/1.1.0/outputs/mongodb